# Where can I find web hosting reviews?

Tags: server, hosting

I'm trying to choose a new hosting service for a WordPress blog, I've stumbled upon several services and most of them look good, so I was trying to find reviews from current user to see what they have to say, is there any website where I can find people's thoughts on the different web hosting companies / services?.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't bother with any of the hosting review sites. Instead ask friends and peers which services they use and if they are any good. Also checkout the userbase and the community at the host you are considering as they will give you a good indication of whether the host is of good quality or not.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be Web Hosting talk forums http://www.webhostingtalk.com/ Also Host Search http://www.hostsearch.com/